# Gpu underload in games

Tags: windows-10, gpu, gaming

Specs:

```
Cpu- ryzen 5 5600x (no integrated graphics)
Gpu- rtx 3070
Ram- 16gb
```

I am currently facing an issue where my gpu will no give the maximum preformance. When I stress my gpu on heaven benchmark i get high results but for some reason when i play games especially "Warzone" it wont give more than 60 fps average and very poor graphic quality. I have tried many things to fix this issue (Not in this particular order):

- Clean uninstalled drivers and reinstalled
- Updated drivers directly from nvidia site
- Adjusted setting via nvidia control panel
- Adjusted game settings using references and self experiment
- Rolled back drivers
- Added the games to the graphic settings pages and selected high preformance
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the games

After all this I still have very low frames. Without OC, stress test reaches over 200 fps but when i overclock (maybe incorrectly) pc gets stuck for a short period and continues to work after sreen goes black and turn back on -i assume gpu reset-

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or if there is a setting I'm missing?

Comment: We can't comment on problems that happen after overclocking.

Comment: @harrymc [citation needed](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @user253751 - The first thing we are going to suggest, if a problem happens while a system is overclocked, is to determine if the problem happens without that overclocked.  If it does not then the only conclusion is that the overclock is unstable.

Comment: @Shaq - "pc gets stuck for a short period and continues to work after screen goes black and turn back on I assume GPU reset" - Windows since Windows Vista has be able to recovery from a crash caused by the display adapter. **Your overclock is unstable.**

Comment: I don't overclock but i attempted it as an experiment to eliminate a possibility as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Shaq A common issue is connecting your monitor to the motherboard instead of directly into the video card. Some motherboards will allow it even without integrated graphics, but with worse performance. Try turning vsync off if you're getting locked to 60

Comment: I've inspected all connections with none incorrect. And v-sync is off.

Comment: Ensure that VSYNC is off in both the settings in the game and in the NVIDIA Control Panel (check within "Manage 3D settings" Global Setting and Program Settings tabs - or reinstall the driver using the "Clean Install" option which will put everything back to the default of "Use the 3D application setting").